# Angular - having 2 datepickers showing different dates

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

So i'm trying to put together two calendars on the sidebar for time selection.
But when i choose the date from the first one, it affects the second one too. The same date is shown there too.
THIS IS .TS COMPONENT

```
export class NgbdDatepickerRange {

  hoveredDate: NgbDate | null = null;

  fromDate: NgbDate;
  toDate: NgbDate | null = null;

  fromCompareDate: NgbDate;
  toCompareDate: NgbDate | null = null;

  constructor(calendar: NgbCalendar) {
    // this.fromDate = calendar.getToday();
    // this.toDate = calendar.getNext(calendar.getToday(), 'd', 10);
  }

  onDateSelection2(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromCompareDate && !this.toCompareDate) {
      this.fromCompareDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromCompareDate && !this.toCompareDate && date.after(this.fromCompareDate)) {
      this.toCompareDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toCompareDate = null;
      this.fromCompareDate = date;
    }
  }

  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
THIS IS THE HTML COMPONENT

Example of the range selection

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" outsideDays="hidden">
</ngb-datepicker>

<ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused">
  <span class="custom-day"
        [class.focused]="focused"
        [class.range]="isRange(date)"
        [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
        (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
        (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>

<ngb-datepicker #dp (dateSelect)="onDateSelection2($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" outsideDays="hidden">
</ngb-datepicker>

<ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused">
  <span class="custom-day"
        [class.focused]="focused"
        [class.range]="isRange(date)"
        [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
        (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
        (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>

<hr>

<pre>From: {{ fromDate | json }} </pre>
<pre>To: {{ toDate | json }} </pre>
```

### DEMO: https://lbnlcm.run.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Can you please provide the editable version of your stackblitz please ? Also, both of your datePicker have `#dp`, is it normal ? shouldn't they be different ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that i'm not being able to create one function for the both datepickers.

Comment: So you are trying tolink your two datepicker ? when one changes, the other should change as well ?

Comment: Well, in the first look when the first one is selected the second one is -1 year ago the same date by default, but the user can change the default second date after.